# Root user on Ubuntu 11.10 AMI?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, user-permissions, amazon-ami

I am new to linux, so this may be a very simple question.

I have created a modified ami using the ubuntu 11.10 as a starting point. All of the tutorials I have found say that to save an instance you must be the root user, but I have only been able to log in as user Ubuntu. How do I log-in as the root user, or gain root authority, on Ubunty 11.10 so I can bundle and save my modified image?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo -su`

type user password

then you are logged as root user.

If you want to enable root user in ubuntu you have to set the root password with :

`sudo -su`

type password

`passwd`

type 2 times the password that you want to assign to the root user.

logout and login again with root user and chosen password ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a root password:

`sudo passwd`

Also examine the /etc/passwd entry to see if root has a valid shell:

`grep root: /etc/passwd`